# Find all combinations with set characters

Tags: python, combinations

I'm new and I promise you I've tried google for the past few hours but I must be using the wrong words and for that why I'm here. I'm trying to find all combinations with some set/fixed/prefixed characters at in certain positions, for example:

4dT_fg_zR         (L M N Q P 0 1 2 3)<-characters to choose from

- 4dTLfgMzR
- 4dTMfgNzR
- 4dTNfgQzR and so forth

Comment: Use `itertools.combinations()`

Comment: Concatenate the 2 letters in the combinations with the fixed parts of the string to create the results you want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an f-string. An f string is a string that is waiting to be formatted with new information.

```
s = "4dT{}fg{}zR"
```

Now you can format those spots with the `.format()` method for strings. For example:

```
for a,b in itertools.combinations("LMNQP0123",2):
    print(s.format(a,b))
```

Comment: "f string" is perhaps a misleading term to use, considering this refers to something very specific in Python 3.x and this is not that.

Comment: If you mean f"" that compiles to a python string upon use, sure I agree with you. However the concept of an f-string existed well before the f"" notation did.